# Checkout page not show redirect after stripe payment

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments

After stripe payment not redirect thank you page I have use WooCommerce  plugin and WooCommerce stripe plugin:

[image]

Comment: please provide more information. not an image.

Comment: This can be usual conflict with your theme and/or plugins. The best option is to disable all plugins except for WooCommerce and Stripe, then test again. If it works, then you know that one of the plugins/themes is creating a conflict.